# Weird issue after upgrading to Nhibernate 3

Tags: nhibernate, informix

Hi
I have a query mapped to take a date field.
After upgrading to NHibernate 3 I get the following error:

```
could not execute query
[ select a.agency_num, cd.comp_name, sd.sib_number, sd.sib_type_label,
ad.add_line1, ad.add_line2, ad.add_line3, ad.add_line4, ad.post_code,
ad.country_label
from
agency a, company_details cd, sib_dets sd, address ad
where
a.contact_ser = cd.contact_ser
and a.contact_ser = sd.contact_ser
and a.contact_ser = ad.contact_ser
and a.current_ser = 10
and a.start_date <= ?
and (a.end_date is null or a.end_date >= ?)
and cd.current_ser = 10
and cd.start_date <= ?
and (cd.end_date is null or cd.end_date >= ?)
and sd.current_ser = 10
and sd.start_date <= ?
and (sd.end_date is null or sd.end_date >= ?)
and ad.current_ser = 10
and ad.start_date <= ?
and (ad.end_date is null or ad.end_date >= ?) ]
  Name:dateValid - Value:18/02/2011 00:00:00
[SQL: select a.agency_num, cd.comp_name, sd.sib_number,
sd.sib_type_label,
ad.add_line1, ad.add_line2, ad.add_line3, ad.add_line4, ad.post_code,
ad.country_label
from
agency a, company_details cd, sib_dets sd, address ad
where
a.contact_ser = cd.contact_ser
and a.contact_ser = sd.contact_ser
and a.contact_ser = ad.contact_ser
and a.current_ser = 10
and a.start_date <= ?
and (a.end_date is null or a.end_date >= ?)
and cd.current_ser = 10
and cd.start_date <= ?
and (cd.end_date is null or cd.end_date >= ?)
and sd.current_ser = 10
and sd.start_date <= ?
and (sd.end_date is null or sd.end_date >= ?)
and ad.current_ser = 10
and ad.start_date <= ?
and (ad.end_date is null or ad.end_date >= ?)]
```

and the inner exception is:
{"The IfxParameter with ParameterName 'p0' is already contained by
this IfxParameterCollection."}

Anyone know why this is? It works fine under the previous version on
NHibernate

Here is my NHibernate code:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession(FACTORY_NAME))
    {
    IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetAllAgents");
    query.SetDateTime("dateValid", dateValid.Date);
    agents = query.List<AgencySearchData>();
    }
```

and here is my mapping file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="SeiDomain"
               namespace="Sei.Domain.Entity">
      <class name="AgencySearchData">
        <id name="AgencyNumber" column="agency_num"/>
        <property name="Name" column="comp_name" />
        <property name="SibNumber" column="sib_number" />
        <property name="SibType" column="sib_type_label" />
        <property name="Address1" column="add_line1" />
        <property name="Address2" column="add_line2" />
        <property name="Address3" column="add_line3" />
        <property name="Address4" column="add_line4" />
        <property name="Postcode" column="post_code" />
        <property name="Country" column="country_label" />
      </class>
      <sql-query name="GetAllAgents">
        <return alias="agencySearchData" class="AgencySearchData"/>
        <![CDATA[select a.agency_num, cd.comp_name, sd.sib_number,
    sd.sib_type_label,
    ad.add_line1, ad.add_line2, ad.add_line3, ad.add_line4, ad.post_code,
    ad.country_label
    from
    agency a, company_details cd, sib_dets sd, address ad
    where
    a.contact_ser = cd.contact_ser
    and a.contact_ser = sd.contact_ser
    and a.contact_ser = ad.contact_ser
    and a.current_ser = 10
    and a.start_date <= :dateValid
    and (a.end_date is null or a.end_date >= :dateValid)
    and cd.current_ser = 10
    and cd.start_date <= :dateValid
    and (cd.end_date is null or cd.end_date >= :dateValid)
    and sd.current_ser = 10
    and sd.start_date <= :dateValid
    and (sd.end_date is null or sd.end_date >= :dateValid)
    and ad.current_ser = 10
    and ad.start_date <= :dateValid
    and (ad.end_date is null or ad.end_date >= :dateValid)]]>
      </sql-query>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be related to [NH-2529](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2529).

See if the fix works for you, and vote for it.